# AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'get_dummies?

Tags: python

I am getting this error. Does anybody know why?

```
  inputs = df.drop('Doctor_Name',axis='columns')
  target = df.Doctor_Name    
  dummies = pd.get_dummies(inputs.Dept_visited)
  dummies.head(3)
```

Comment: Can you share the full code that comes before these four lines of code?

Answer (score 0):

I hope, it works for your solutions. Do you import pandas

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[
    {"doctor_id": 1, "doctor_name": "Sadia", "doctor_gender": "Female", "Dept_visited": "Family Medicine"},
    {"doctor_id": 2, "doctor_name": "Saad", "doctor_gender": "Male", "dept_visited": "Psychiatry"}
])
df
inputs = df.drop('doctor_name',axis='columns')
target = df.doctor_name    
dummies = pd.get_dummies(inputs.Dept_visited)
dummies.head(3)
```